# Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, get-request, jsonexception

I make "GET" request in order to get a JSON object. When i try to read the response, an error is thrown. The error is descriped in the header. 
It's a really miracle for me, because when i run the app on the emulator or in the browser, i get JSON response, everything is ok. But when i run it on real phone, i see this error....
Will be grateful for any answer. Here is my code.

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
StringBuilder builder;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("log", "background error " + e);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    Log.e("log", "response " + s);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        Log.e("log", "JSON = " + jsonObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("log", "post error " + e);
    }

}
```

}

This is the String i get in post Execute

```
<html>                            <body>                                
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>                                    
window.location.href = '/';                                </script>                            
</body>                        </html>
```

And here is the error i get

```
05-04 08:56:19.989 2731-2731/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 
<html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-04 08:56:19.989 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-04 08:56:19.989 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.
<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
05-04 08:56:19.989 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.
<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
05-04 08:56:19.989 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
com.example.dshahzadyan.gettest.Task.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:64)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
com.example.dshahzadyan.gettest.Task.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:33)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 08:56:19.999 2731-2731/? W/System.err:     at
```

Comment: Can you post your json response

Comment: The answer you get back simply is not JSON but a HTML document.

Comment: When you are using your phone , you are getting <html> response , which cannot be parsed into a json object.

Comment: There is an exception in your Web API thats why its returning the error instead of JSON object.

Comment: here is JSON response. Sorry, its in russian)
http://api.webbankir.com/props

I cant real understand it because I've been sent the same request using device much times and there had been no problems til today))

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaShahid you may be right. But in this case why I get no problems while using an emulator?

Comment: What does the emulator print?

Comment: Cross check the url to which you are making request. May url is wrong

Comment: @Denny the emulator prints JSON. I can simply parse it....

Comment: @SatishKumar I get the same problem in any case.... I've tried with million URLs....

Comment: hey guys i solved this problem. It turned out that my wi-fi got problems)).... Now everything is ok.... Thank everyone for answers

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is of type html and not json. So, onPostExecute method when the response string which is of html format is not able to convert to json. Make sure the url you are trying to hit is sending the json and not html

Comment: thank you for answer, but the problem is that the response is of JSON format. I get response in JSON format when i run programm on emulator but not on real device.

Comment: I would agree with you if i hadn't try to make request using other URL. The effect is the same